# is it possible to create custom legend items

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

**I want to create custom legend item instead of the default one which just shows series 0, is it possible to do so when creating a SfCatesian line chart ?**

```
SfCartesianChart(
          legend: Legend(
            isVisible: true,
            position: LegendPosition.right,
            toggleSeriesVisibility: true,
            title: LegendTitle(text:'Sales by day',)),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
          plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
          enableAxisAnimation: true,
          primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
              majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent)),
          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
              minimum: 0,
              maximum: 5,
              interval: 1,
              opposedPosition: true,
              axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
              majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(size: 0)),
          series: <LineSeries<_ChartData, String>>[
      LineSeries<_ChartData, String>(
        name: "Daily sales",
          animationDuration: 2500,
          dataSource: <_ChartData>[
            _ChartData('Mon', 3,  Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1)),
            _ChartData('Tues', 4, Color.fromRGBO(0, 255, 0, 1)),
            _ChartData('Wed', 3, Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 255, 1)),
          ],
          xValueMapper: (_ChartData sales, _) => sales.x,
          yValueMapper: (_ChartData sales, _) => sales.y,
          pointColorMapper: (_ChartData sales, _) => sales.lineColor,
          width: 2,)];,
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suggest you the [legendItemBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/Legend/legendItemBuilder.html) property in the legend, using this you can be able to customize the legend item based on your requirement. We have shared the demo sample, UG, and KB link below for your reference.

Sample: https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/cartesian-charts/legend/chart-with-customized-legend

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/legend#legend-item-template

KB: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/13055/